# MySQL query not using index in production but using in test environment

Tags: mysql

One of my MySQL query used for update is using index of table present in Test environment but whereas it's not using index for the same table with same structure in Production.So can anyone tell the reason and solution for this.

```
UPDATE APA_Pended_Demand apd
INNER JOIN APA_Generic_Demand_Details agd
    ON agd.demandID = apd.demandID 
SET apd.genericDemandId = agd.genericDemandId
WHERE apd.isPend = 1 AND
      agd.genericDemandId != '' AND
      agd.genericDemandId IS NOT NULL AND
      apd.reactivateDate > UTC_TIMESTAMP() AND
      agd.status < 300 AND
      apd.ID BETWEEN 1 AND 10000 ;
```

Comment: Assuming that you have same indices on dev and prod env, mysql may choose not to use index depending on the data size. If there is less amount of data then optimizer may choose to scan the entire table instead of using index since it would be faster to scan than using the index table.

Comment: What are the differences between the test environment and production?

Comment: The test environment contains around 5300 rows and production contains around 3 lakhs rows

Comment: The table structures and indexing are same